# How to SELECT top N rows that sum to a certain amount?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose:

```
MyTable
--
Amount
1
2
3
4
5
```

`MyTable` only has one column, `Amount`, with 5 rows. They are not necessarily in increasing order.
How can I create a function, which takes a `@SUM INT`, and returns the **TOP N rows** that sum to this amount?
So for input 6, I want

```
Amount
1
2
3
```

Since 1 + 2 + 3 = 6. 2 + 4 / 1 + 5 won't work since I want **TOP N ROWS**
For 7/8/9/10, I want

```
Amount
1
2
3
4
```

I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 R2, if this matters.

Comment: Couldn't the sum be a bit ambiguous? I mean 3+5 = 8 for example

Comment: @Elias I said multiple times TOP N rows.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?. And the rows need to be sum in amount order, right?

Comment: @Lamak SQL SERVER 2008 R2; the rows need to be sumed from top to bottom order.

Comment: Do you have an id defining the order that one can order by?

Comment: This sounds like a riddle or homework assignment haha

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes you can assume that, since in my DB I do have the  records ordered by another column than "amount".

Comment: Can the downvoters tell me why this question got downvoted?

Comment: I did not down-vote the question, but the two votes to close (looks like for "unclear what you're asking") might give a clue.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't understand which part is ambiguous. I explicitly mentioned TOP N ROWS several times. And the downvoters don't bother to leave a comment.

Comment: @octref well to me TOP needs a definition, since a table is an unordered bag of rows unless you have an ORDER BY. So I understand why people are being forced to ask for clarification. The accepted answer does not match your updated requirements because your original requirements were unclear. So I don't feel that any activity here is really unjustified. As for down-votes without comments, yep, such is Stack Overflow, sorry.

Comment: @AaronBertrand All right that makes sense. I should have mentioned this is an ordered output table. My original table was too complex and I was trying to give a simplified example here.

Comment: @octref once someone asked how order was defined, you could have just added a second column with values 1,2,3,4,etc. And to be honest, I'm still not clear what you're trying to accomplish (never mind how I would solve it).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I guess I'll just post a new question, this time eliminating as much ambiguity as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach:

```
select t1.amount 
from MyTable t1
left join MyTable t2 on t1.amount > t2.amount
group by t1.amount
having coalesce(sum(t2.amount),0) < 7
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7410c/10).

Comment: Did you tested this query with duplicated values in `amount` column ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Good point, I haven't thought of that. And indeed this doesn't work with duplicated values in `amount`.

Comment: @octref you need to update your question because you are being ambiguous. First the table was supposed to have only one column, so it was assumed that you needed them ordered by that column. If not, and if there can be duplicated values, you need to specify the column by which you want the rows to be ordered by

Comment: @Lamak Right, I shouldn't do so much edit after people have given their answers. Thanks, I'll just mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

Saying "top N rows" is indeed ambiguous when it comes to relational databases.

I assume that you want to order by "amount" ascending.

I would add a second column (to a table or view) like "sum_up_to_here", and create something like that:

```
create view mytable_view as 
select 
 mt1.amount, 
 sum(mt2.amount) as sum_up_to_here 
from 
 mytable mt1 
 left join mytable mt2 on (mt2.amount < mt1.amount)
group by mt1.amount
```

or:

```
create view mytable_view as 
select 
 mt1.amount, 
 (select sum(amount) from mytable where amount < mt1.amount) 
from mytable mt1
```

and then I would select the final rows:

```
select amount from mytable_view where sum_up_to_here < (some value)
```

If you don't bother about performance you may of course run it in one query:

```
select amount from 
(
select 
 mt1.amount, 
 sum(mt2.amount) as sum_up_to_here 
from 
 mytable mt1 
 left join mytable mt2 on (mt2.amount < mt1.amount)
group by mt1.amount
) t where sum_up_to_here < 20
```

Comment: But actually the Table is an output table. What I have is a table with multiple columns (Amount, B, C, D). The output might be ORDER BY B, or C, or D, so I can't just save the sum into a table.

Comment: You don't need to save the partial sums. I did so to suggest that counting that may be costly and it would be better to do it only once. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who needs this, try this solution.

**FYI**: This only works on SQL servers after version 2008

But first, you need a way to order the table data, or else you won't get consistent results. Let's assume `MyTable` as an extra column named **A** where we want to order the table.

```
with MyTableCte as (
  select *,
         sum(t.Amount) over (order by A) as cumulative
  from MyTable t
)
select *
from MyTableCte r
where r.Amount + <your value> - r.cumulative > 0

             -- Sample data output for cte result
             -- for sum quantity 6, we want the top 3 rows
             --------------------------------------------------------
             -- | A      | Amount | cumulative |
             -- |--------|--------|------------|
             -- | 1      | 1      | 1          |
             -- | 2      | 2      | 3          |
             -- | 3      | 3      | 6          |
             -- | 8      | 4      | 10         |
             -- | 10     | 5      | 15         |
             --------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012 you can use this shortcut to get a result like Grzegorz's.

```
SELECT amount 
FROM (
  SELECT * ,
  SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY amount ASC) AS total
  from demo
) T
WHERE total <= 6
```

A fiddle in the hand... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b8506/6

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 doesn't allow `SUM(col) OVER(ORDER BY ...)`

Comment: Whithout the `ORDER BY` this doesn't works as intended by op, it will give the `SUM` of the whole table. And you can't `ORDER BY` something else, since that is exclusive for SQL Server 2012

Comment: @Lanak He would need something to order by, when I posted the answer there was no mention of 2008.

Comment: @Hogan But there was a mention before I made my first comment saying that this doesn't works on SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @Lamak - I'm not sure of your point right now.  Leave your -1 if it makes you happy.  I believe this answer could be useful to someone and that is the point of SO for me.

Comment: @Hogan My point was just replying to your previous comment about  being no mention of SQL Server 2008. And I did leave the downvote there because the question is meant for SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @Hogan it doesn't answer this question for *this* OP (or anyone else who comes along and isn't on 2012). I'm okay with providing a SQL Server 2012 solution to the problem, but only *in addition to* a solution that actually helps the OP.

Comment: sqlserver2008!=sqlserver2012

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server you can use CDEs to make it pretty simple to read.

Here is a CDE I did to sum up totals used in sequence.  The CDE is similar to the joins above, and holds the total up to any given index.  Outside of the CDE I join it back to the original table so I can select it along with other fields.

```
;with summrp as (
    select m1.idx, sum(m2.QtyReq) as sumUsed
    from #mrpe m1
    join #mrpe m2 on m2.idx <= m1.idx
    group by m1.idx
)

select RefNum, RefLineSuf, QtyReq, ProjectedDate, sumUsed from #mrpe m
join summrp on summrp.idx=m.idx
```